# Is there a way to create a matrix that would contain functions as input values in R?

Tags: r, function, matrix, ode

For example, the MATLAB code for something I need to write looks like this

```
 f = @(x) [ 100*x(1) - 4*x(1)*x(2);

     -20*x(2) + 0.01*x(1)*x(2)];

 J = @(x) [100-4*x(2), -4*x(1);

      0.01*x(2), -20+0.01*x(1)];
```

What would be an analog in R to store functions as matrix values?
In R, I tried

```
 rabbits <- function(x) { #defined a function

100*x(1) - 4*x(1)*x(2) }


 foxes <- function(x) { #defined a second function

 -20*x(2) + 0.01*x(1)*x(2)}

function_vector <- matrix(0, 2, 1) # created a 0 matrix to later append values

function_vector[1,1] <- function_vector[1,1] + rabbits #added values to 0 matrix

function_vector[2,1] <- function_vector[2,1] + foxes
```

Apparently, I can't store functions in matrixes, as it gives me an error "non-numeric argument to binary operator". Generally, I need this matrix for manual two-dimensional root finding, so if you know any other way to code it (apart from inbuilt functions), then I would also appreciate that :)

Comment: Your Matlab code only shows the definition of the two functions, right? So it’s the exact analog to your R functions `rabbits` and `foxes`. Where is the part that you can’t translate to R?

Comment: Actually hang on, your Matlab functions are *returning* matrices, aren’t they (my Matlab knowledge is a bit rusty)? You can do the exact same thing in R, of course.

Comment: @KonradRudolph with these code lines in MATLAB the two functions are not only defined but also already stored within a matrix that facilitates further manipulation in finding roots. In R, I first defined the functions, then tried to append them to a zero matrix, but R does not allow storing functions in matrixes

Answer (score 0):

You can store functions in a list array. It is created by setting the `dim` attribute of a list.

```r
# works without names, only added them to illustrate the order they will appear in the array in. 
l <- list(
  f11 = \(x) x,
  f21 = \(x) x^2,
  f12 = \(x) 2*x,
  f22 = \(x) 2*x^2
)

dim(l) <- c(2, 2)  

l[1,2]
#> [[1]]
#> \(x) 2*x
```

Alternatively, you can also store functions in list variables of data frames. I am using a tibble here, because the constructor `data.frame()` doesn't like lists of functions for some reason. But it is possible to coerce it to a plain data frame if you prefer.

```r
d <- tibble::tibble(
  f1 = list(\(x) x,
            \(x) 2*x),
  f2 = list(\(x) x^2,
            \(x) 2*x^2)
)

d
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   f1     f2    
#>   <list> <list>
#> 1 <fn>   <fn>  
#> 2 <fn>   <fn>

as.data.frame(d)
#>                     f1                     f2
#> 1     function (x) , x     function (x) , x^2
#> 2 function (x) , 2 * x function (x) , 2 * x^2
```

Note that I have used the shorthand function syntax `\(...) ...` here. If you have an R version older than 4.1 you will have to replace it with `function(...) {...}`.

<sup>Created on 2022-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Use `data.frame(f1 = I(<list>), f2 = I(<list>))`.